# looking to browse wily werewolf source

Tags: git, source-code

The wiki says source for a release can be browsed at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-.git. release = "wily-werewolf" does not exist. Is it 15.10/wily werewolf not available yet?

Comment: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-wily.git/

Answer (score 1):

That is only the source for the kernel. All of the source packages for all the packages included in Ubuntu, are however, hosted in the archive and mirrors. If you install the `ubuntu-dev-tools` package, you can then grab the source for any package using the `pull-lp-source` tool.